# Vue + Firebase "The given sign-in provider is disabled"

Tags: firebase, vue.js

I've read 2 years old posts about this problem but couldn't find an answer.
I'm very new to web so i got read and fallowed the this: https://savvyapps.com/blog/definitive-guide-building-web-app-vuejs-firebase to get my hands wet. Everything is working perfectly on the local server but i wanted to deploy the project to firebase so i can see how that is going to work. I did everything, the project is deployed but when i try ty sign in or sign up i get this error:

"The given sign-in provider is disabled for this Firebase project. Enable it in the Firebase console, under the sign-in method tab of the Auth section."

The Email/Password provider is enabled. I tried disabling/enabling it, waiting a minute, F5 refresh page, still the same. I searched in the firebase docs, looked at the release notes, searched in vue docs, searching in google, but couldn't find anything useful to fix the problem. I don't know why this problem appears when it's working on the local server.

When running the firebase init command i used the default names for the files and the public folder. CLI features i chose Firestore and hosting.

I reinstalled node, vue, vuex, firebase tools, rebuild the project using the "npm run build", everything that i could think of but i still get the error.
I copy pasted the files from the "dist" folder to the default public folder, and i kept the 404 file.

This is the firebase.json

```
{
  "firestore": {
    "rules": "firestore.rules",
    "indexes": "firestore.indexes.json"
  },
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Here are the dependencies from the package.json file

```
"dependencies": {
    "firebase": "^5.4.1",
    "firebaseui": "^3.4.0",
    "moment": "^2.22.2",
    "vue": "^2.5.17",
    "vue-material": "^1.0.0-beta-10.2",
    "vue-router": "^3.0.1",
    "vuex": "^3.0.1"
  },
```

I added the firebaseui because i thought it was needed to be installed even though i'm not gonna use it.

If i missed any info that could be useful, please tell me!

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/189

Comment: Can you add a print screen of the Firebase console, "Authentication" part, "Signin methods" tab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***This is not an answer but the content is too long to be added as a comment***

What happens if you try creating a user with a simple HTML/JavaScript page, i.e. not in your vue.js app?

You can use the following HTML page. Just adapt the config values to the ones of your project and open it in a browser.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.0.3/firebase-app.js"></script>
   <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.0.3/firebase-auth.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<script>
  // Initialize Firebase
  var config = {
    apiKey: "....",
    authDomain: "....",
    databaseURL: "....",
    projectId: "....",
    storageBucket: "....",
    messagingSenderId: "...."
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);


  firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword("myuser@mail.com", "myuserpassword")
        .then((userCredential) => {  
            console.log(userCredential); 
            user = userCredential.user;
            console.log(user);  
         }).catch(function(error) {
                // Handle Errors here.
                var errorCode = error.code;
                var errorMessage = error.message;
                if (errorCode == 'auth/weak-password') {
                  alert('The password is too weak')
                } else {
                  alert(errorMessage)
                }
                console.log(error)
         });


</script>

<body>
</html>
```

Comment: I found my mistake. I have 3 firebase projects and i copied the config data from the wrong project..... Now it's working. I feel soo stupid that i didn't saw this, in the past 3 days.

Comment: It happened to everybody :-)

Comment: @Quetzalcoalt I feel you mate… had a Problem where i wondered why my Thing didnt work while my Images where .jpg but my Code had .png and i needed 2 days to find it since the docs of the library used .png